# POST over HTTPS Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, https

I need to call an external url to pull down some information from a remote database.

I tried setting up my call like this:

```
post_params = {'a' => 'b', 'b' => 'c',}
resp = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('https:/my.remoteserver.com/'), post_params)
```

This returns with a 400 Bad Request, however, due to the fact that the url is HTTPS.

If I format the call as a GET, however, and do something like this:

```
url = URI.parse("https:/my.remoteserver.com?a=b&b=c")
result = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, use_ssl: true, verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do
  |http| http.get url.request_uri, 'User-Agent' => 'MyLib v1.2'
end
```

Everything works fine. Unfortunately in my specific case I can't use GET. I assume there is a way to do this over POST but I just don't know what that would be. If anyone could help me out with this I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: is this useful? http://javazquez.com/juan/2008/12/07/ruby-https-posting/

Comment: Ok just submitted as answer then

Answer (score 7):

The key part of the other answer's link, and cause of your problem could be because you need to set `use_ssl = true` on the `Net::HTTP` element:

Example:

```
post_params = {'a' => 'b', 'b' => 'c',}

uri = URI 'https:/my.remoteserver.com/'

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https'

resp = http.post_form(uri, post_params)
```

Comment: undefined method `post_form`